# Xerces2-j XML Schema Attribute / Element Declaration data type

Tags: java, xsd, xerces

I'm using Apache's Xerces2-j to parse my XSD. I am trying to get the datatype information for the element / attribute declarations in the XSD.

Here's an example XSD:

```
<xs:element name="Pretzel">
    ...
    <xs:attribute name="Flavor" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="ProductID" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
    ...
</xs:element>
```

In this case, I'd want to get the datatypes of the *Flavor* and *ProductID* attributes. According to the [W3C Schema API](http://www.w3.org/Submission/2004/SUBM-xmlschema-api-20040122/xml-schema-api.html#XSAttributeDecl-atypevc) and [its Xerces2-j implementation](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xs/org/apache/xerces/xs/XSAttributeDeclaration.html#getActualVCType%28%29), XSAttributeDeclaration's getActualVCType() will get me what I want. But for me that method always returns 45, which is **UNAVAILABLE_DT**. Is this a bug in Xerces2-j, or am I just understanding the API wrong? If I am, I'd appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to use the method

```
XSAttributeDeclaration.getTypeDefinition(); // returns XSSimpleTypeDefinition
```

for simple types and/or possibly

```
XSAttributeDeclaration.getEnclosingCTDefinition(); // returns XSComplexTypeDefinition
```

for complex types.

The method getActualVCType() is deprecated, and its alternative call getValueConstraintValue().getActualValueType() looks into a so-called [value constraint](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-1-20010502/#a-simple_type_definition)
which is not what you are looking for. This argument is also supported by the code in [XSAttributeDecl.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.xerces/com.springsource.org.apache.xerces/2.9.1/org/apache/xerces/impl/xs/XSAttributeDecl.java?av=h#XSAttributeDecl):

```
       // variable definition
48     // value constraint type: default, fixed or !specified
49     short fConstraintType = XSConstants.VC_NONE;
```

and

```
183    public short getActualVCType() {
184        return getConstraintType() == XSConstants.VC_NONE ?
185               XSConstants.UNAVAILABLE_DT :
186               fDefault.actualValueType;
187    }
```

with

```
136
137    public short getConstraintType() {
138        return fConstraintType;
139    }
```

suggests that you are indeed getting UNAVAILABLE_DT because it is not set. I suggest looking into the XSSimpleTypeDefinition's methods, it looks promising to me.